# Trying to assign an alarm with javafx

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx, timer, alarm

Hello there brilliant minds of stack overflow!
I am currently working on a personal program that should ultimately function as a reminder every 20 or so minutes to do another task(one of those productivity-boosting things) as well as a basic timer that will tell me when my shift is over @ work. 
I am having difficulty parsing the appropriate textfields into an int to place in the timers I am making(aswell as the profile object).
I know there are probably a couple ways to go about this please let me know your thoughts, here is my code so far:

```
    package javafxneoalarm;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.FontWeight;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author Hvd
 */
public class JavaFXNeoAlarm extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Neo Alarm");
        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        grid.setHgap(10);
        grid.setVgap(10);
        grid.setPadding(new Insets(25, 25, 25, 25));

        Text sceneTitle = new Text("Welcome! \nPlease Enter Name &\nThe Hour/Minute of your Alarm");
        sceneTitle.setFont(Font.font("Helvetica", FontWeight.NORMAL, 20));
        grid.add(sceneTitle, 0, 0, 2, 1);

        Button btn = new Button("Lets go!");
        HBox hbBtn = new HBox(10);
        hbBtn.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT);
        hbBtn.getChildren().add(btn);
        grid.add(hbBtn, 1, 4);

        final Text actiontarget = new Text();
                grid.add(actiontarget, 1, 6);

        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent e){
                actiontarget.setFill(Color.FIREBRICK);
                actiontarget.setText("Count-down initiated \nMay the force be with you");
            }
        });

        Label userName = new Label("Name:  \n");
        grid.add(userName, 0, 1);

        TextField userTextField = new TextField();
        grid.add(userTextField, 1, 1);

        Label a1 = new Label("Alarm1:  \n");
        grid.add(a1, 0, 2);

        TextField a1BoxHr = new TextField();
        grid.add(a1BoxHr, 1, 2);


        TextField a1BoxMin = new TextField();
        grid.add(a1BoxMin, 2, 2);

        Label a2 = new Label("Alarm2:  \n");
        grid.add(a2, 0, 3);

        TextField a2BoxHr = new TextField();
        grid.add(a2BoxHr, 1, 3);

        TextField a2BoxMin = new TextField();
        grid.add(a2BoxMin, 2, 3);





        Scene scene = new Scene(grid, 300, 275);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();


        // double 1BoxHr = Double.parseDouble(a1BoxHr);
        // profileOne = new Profile(userTextField, (((a1BoxHr*60)+a1BoxMin)*60), (((a2BoxHr*60)+a2BoxMin)*60));

    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);

        Timer alarmA1 = new Timer();
        Timer alarmA2 = new Timer();

        TimerTask task = new TimerTask()
        {
            public void run(){
                // when timer goes off
            }
        };
        Profile profileOne;


    }

}
```

And the profile class:

```
package javafxneoalarm;

/**
 *
 * @author Hvd
 */
public class Profile {
// declare instance variables
    private String user;
    private double alarm1;
    private double alarm2;

    // constructor (overloaded, has new instance variable or parameter to apply maths through)

    public Profile(String newUser, double newAlarm1, double newAlarm2){
        user = newUser;

        alarm1 = newAlarm1;

        alarm2 = newAlarm2;   
    }

    // getters

    public String getUser(){
        return user;
    }

    public double getAlarm1(){
        return alarm1;
    }
    public double getAlarm2(){
        return alarm2;
    }

    // setters

    public void setUser(String newUser){
        user = newUser;
    }

    public void setAlarm1(double newAlarm1){
        alarm1 = newAlarm1;
    }

    public void setAlarm2(double newAlarm2){
        alarm2 = newAlarm2;
    }




}
```

So basically how do I assign the inputs to an alarm that will go off after x amount of time, also I would like the window to close/minimize to tray after inputting/submitting the profile information and re-open when the alarm goes off but that might be a challenge for another day.

Thanks a lot guys, I look forward to continuing this creative endeavor :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to assign a double depending on the input in the textfield, I should be placing the assignment inside the button click:

```
btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e){
            actiontarget.setFill(Color.FIREBRICK);
            actiontarget.setText("Count-down initiated \nMay the force be with you");

            String BUser = userTextField.getText(); // sets variable BUser from inputs

            double BAlarm1Hrs = Double.parseDouble(a1BoxHr.getText());
            double BAlarm1Min = Double.parseDouble(a1BoxMin.getText());
            double BAlarm1 = (((BAlarm1Hrs * 60) * 60) + (BAlarm1Min * 60)); // sets BAlarm1 to seconds of hrs and minutes inputted 


            double BAlarm2Hrs = Double.parseDouble(a2BoxHr.getText());
            double BAlarm2Min = Double.parseDouble(a2BoxMin.getText());
            double BAlarm2 = (((BAlarm2Hrs * 60) * 60) + (BAlarm2Min * 60));


            Profile profileA = new Profile(BUser, BAlarm1, BAlarm2);


            }
    });
```